# What to do when we can't login to the superuser

Tags: 16.04

While trying to create a new  file in php I granted ownership permission to www-data. There onwards I can't login to the superuser session but I can login to the guest session. The login screen asks for password and on typing password thereafter it redisplays the screen.
What to do?

Comment: Malayali aano??

Answer (score 0):

Restart the system , immediately hold and press shift key  you will enter into GRUB.There you can find recovery mode .After clicking recovery mode , you may find root option [Drop to root shell prompt] . click that and try to change the permissions and resume normal boot .Hope It may help you